# Curvature of a particle move

Tags: kinematics, simulations, curvature, software, brownian-motion

I'm simulating a particle movement following a normal distribution. How this is done:

My particle has a constant speed `v` and every step the particle move, I calculate an angle `teta` for then, calculates the next position using Pythagoras making `v` the hypotenuse. That means that each step size is `v`.

[image]

`teta` is calculated using a normal random numbers generator. For a fixed standard deviation `std` and an initial `mean`, I calculate an angle and for each step, I set the mean as the angle calculated.

[image]

The red lines length is always `v` which is the same of the distance between position_n and position_n+1.
A code to help explain better:

```
mean = get_mean_value()
std = get_std_value()
v = get_speed_value()

for each step, do:
    teta = random_normal_number(mean, std)
    actual_pos = particle.get_position()
    particle.move(teta, actual_pos)
    mean = teta
```

**QUESTION:**

Every step lasts 1 second, in other words, going from position_n to position_n+1 lasts 1 second. When the world, where the particle is, is very small, 1 step/second is very big. So a created a `divider` variable that halves that 1 step/second:

```
divider = 1 yields 1 step/second
divider = 2 yields 2 step/second
divider = 3 yields 3 step/second
...
```

The problem is when I increase this divider, the `curvature` of this movement reduces. Look the image of the particle track for two different experiments:

[image]

I'd like to keep the curvature always the same being possible to variate the `divider`. I know that I have to start wrapping the `divider` with the standard deviation of the gaussian, because when It's small, the width of the normal curve is smaller and then the particle movement is less curved because I randomly choose a angle closer of the mean.

I'd like to know if you guys have some ideas or hints for how can I wrap `divider` and `std` to keep the curvature of the movement even changing the divider for different experiments.

(I don't know if it's a Physics or Math question.)

Comment: I think this is a (two-dimensional) [Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion). Even though the concept derives from physics, mathematicians (and economists) have done a lot with it. Given the (unnatural) 'steps', I'd think they (the mathematicians) would be better at it. I believe the continuous case is called a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process.

Comment: I erased my answer, I do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thought experiment: after N steps, each of which create a change in angle $\Delta \theta$, we should end up with a normal distribution of angles with a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$. When you change the step length, you therefore need to scale the standard deviation by the square root of that change, so that after moving the same distance (albeit with a different number of steps), you end up with the same normal distribution (standard deviation) of the direction - and, I assume, the curvature.

Here is a bit of Matlab code to test this:

```
% 2D random motion
N0 = 1000;
sigma = 1.0;
step = 1;
theta = 0;

div = [1,5,20];
figure

for jj = 1:numel(div)
    divider = div(jj);
    N = N0 * divider;
    X=zeros(1,N);
    Y=zeros(1,N);
    theta = 0;
    dTheta = (rand(1,N)-0.5)*sigma/sqrt(divider);
    x=0; y=0;

    for ii=1:numel(dTheta)
        theta = theta + dTheta(ii);
        dx = step * cos(theta)/divider;
        dy = step * sin(theta)/divider;
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        X(ii)=x;
        Y(ii)=y;
    end

    subplot(1,numel(div),jj)
    plot(X,Y)
    title(sprintf('divider = %d',divider))
    xlim([-100 100])
    ylim([-100 100])
    axis equal
end
```

Which produces the following images:

[image]

Having changed the step size by 20x, I find it sufficiently convincing.

Comment: very nice!! But I just didn't understand well why sigma/sqrt(divider)...

Comment: All I did was consider the distribution of angles after N steps: when you add N random variates with standard deviation $\sigma$ you end up with a distribution with standard deviation $\sqrt{N}\sigma$. So if you want the same distribution of angles after you have traveled a certain distance, then you need to scale the size of the step accordingly. And that's what I did...

Comment: That's very very nice! Worked here and I understood the idea. Thanks!!